# OpenVPN connection fails from RHEL 7.3 client on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, openvpn, rhel7

I have a working `OpenVPN` configuration on `Windows 7`. I am able to connect to it via the GUI as well as from the command line (`openvpn --config .\openvpn.ovpn`).

Here is the config file:

```
## acme.ovpn ##
client
proto tcp
dev tun
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert mycert.crt
key mykey.key
remote <REMOTE_IP> 443
route <SOME_OTHER_IP> 255.255.255.0
resolv-retry infinite
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
```

I copied all my config files over to an `EC2` instance of `RHEL 7.3` and [installed openvpn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/343214/23944). However, when I try to run `sudo openvpn --config ./openvpn.ovpn`), the trace ends up showing

```
Wed Feb  8 14:52:27 2017 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Wed Feb  8 14:52:32 2017 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Wed Feb  8 14:52:32 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Wed Feb  8 14:52:32 2017 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]<OPENVPN_IP>:443 [nonblock]
Wed Feb  8 14:52:42 2017 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]<OPENVPN_IP>:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection timed out
Wed Feb  8 14:52:57 2017 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]<OPENVPN_IP>:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection timed out
Wed Feb  8 14:53:13 2017 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]<OPENVPN_IP>:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection timed out
Wed Feb  8 14:53:28 2017 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]<OPENVPN_IP>:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection timed out
Wed Feb  8 14:53:43 2017 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]<OPENVPN_IP>:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection timed out
Wed Feb  8 14:53:58 2017 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]<OPENVPN_IP>:443 failed, will try again in 5 seconds: Connection timed out
```

Please note that the EC2 instance is just an openvpn client, not a server, as has been misunderstood. I am trying to establish a connection from it to a server, which is what the above log placeholder  is the IP of.

**Why does the same configuration fail on the cloud VM that succeeds locally on Windows 7 and what should I do to fix it?**

This question has also been asked [here](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23402).

**RELATED:**

[Getting "Cannot ioctl TUNSETIFF tun: Operation not permitted" when trying to connect to OpenVPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/647231/getting-cannot-ioctl-tunsetiff-tun-operation-not-permitted-when-trying-to-con)

[How to connect to OpenVPN access server from Linux](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/docs/admin-guides/182-how-to-connect-to-access-server-with-linux-clients.html)

Comment: Check your firewalls.  The error message doesn't seem to show you making any connection at all.

Comment: You might be right. I'm checking with my network people